# Angular2 typescript import all classes from one file

Tags: angular, typescript, import, circular-reference

I am using this kind of structure for folders that contain modules.
This is a simplified core folder

```
-- core
   |-- a.service.ts
   |-- b.service.ts
   |-- c.service.ts
   |-- core.module.ts
   |-- index.ts
```

The module imports all classes except for index. Index exports all classes.

I like this because from other files, say from components, I can import any service via `import {ServiceName} from '../core/index'` and I get the nice intellisense list of all services when I start typing within the brackets in the import statement.

This was all nice and well, until I hit the 'unknown dependencies' error for some of the classes the files refer to.
`Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for DummyComponent: (Http, ?).`

The error goes away if I import the service referencing the file directly.
`import {AService} from '../core/a.service'`

I have two questions:

1. Why does this happen? This looks like a circular reference problem. But AService doesn't have any dependencies, so it shouldn't be.
2. How can I achieve this behaviour? What I am trying to emulate is the same as importing HttpModule or Http from @angular/core. I looked at the folder structure and it seems to me it is using the same logic as mine.

Comment: Please, provide relevant code instead of describing it.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Since upgrading my Angular2 CLI I have started hitting param resolve issues. I am going to remove all Barrels from my app

Comment: HI @Rodney and sorry for the late reply. I have managed to solve my problem but I can't say I totally understood it. I have flipped around the order of the modules I export in my index file, making sure that what is depended on is exported first. That solved it. That said I haven't managed to reproduce the error in plnkr when doing exactly the opposite. "Param not resolved" errors generally speaking arise when there is some circular dependency between modules, or when dependencies are imported in some unfeasible order. In the worst case you can try and import with `forwardRef`